# Spring data r2dbc update

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

I have a table with non-auto generated primary key which is basically a foreign key.
So, using withId method as said in the documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.2.3/reference/html/#reference

Creating a new instance is working fine. But, updating the instance without selecting is giving duplicate error. Its not considering that as an update and trying to insert the record.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `project_contact` (
  `project_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `prj_project_id` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`project_id`)
)
```

**Model class,**

```
public class ProjectContact {

    @Id
    private final Long id;
    private final long projectId;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;

    public static ProjectContact of(long projectId, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        return new ProjectContact(null, projectId, firstName, lastName, email);
    }

    
    public ProjectContact(Long id, long projectId, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public ProjectContact withId(Long id) {
        return new ProjectContact(id, this.projectId, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email);
    }
}
```

Here, projectId is a foreign key and hence using withId.

Creating new instance works fine.

```
Project prj = Project.of(....);

projectRespository.save(prj);
```

Updating the instance without select, throws duplicate error since not setting id thru the code.

```
 Project prj = Project.of(....);
    
    projectRespository.save(prj);
```

**Error :-**

```
Caused by: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcDataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '15' for key 'project_contact.PRIMARY'
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:94) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ SQL "INSERT INTO project_contact (project_id, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" [DatabaseClient]
Stack trace:
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:94) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.TextQueryHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:317) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
        at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.TextQueryHandler.accept(QueryFlow.java:292) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Since your Project.of is not setting any id hence insertion will happen. You will have to set id for update to happen you can look for more information regarding this on doc.